# How do I identify resource hogs on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, profiling

I have installed a package of Firefox extensions that installed a few extensions to my Firefox.
Recently I have noticed, that the resource consumption of the Firefox process rose to unacceptable levels for my rather weak Laptop.

How can I identify the add-ons responsible for this? I do not want to uninstall all the add-ons since I think some of them really make my life easier. Is there a way to profile my Firefox plugins, preferably over a period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable each extension, then enable one. Do a few hour's worth of browsing, then open a new tab and go to `about:memory` to see detailed information about the memory consumption. If it is too high then you will know that that extension is a resource hog. Also, check `about:compartments` for "ghost windows" and compartments that are still listed even though they should not be - this is an indication of a memory leak that you should report to Mozilla or the author of the extension.

Note that this would be more accurate/precise if you used a special script that opened 100 tabs at a time, then closed them and then checked the memory. Also, it is a really good idea to disable all extensions first to get an idea of what the normal memory usage should be/is.

Comment: loaded 100 pages* merely opening the tabs uses a negligible amount of memory compared to loading (moderately intensive) pages.

Comment: When I said "100 tabs" I meant "100 sites". At the time, I was actually thinking of a script that automatically opened the top 100 most popular websites, but I can't currently find it.

Answer (score 0):

[Known problems list.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Problematic_extensions)
However, sometimes the only way is to uninstall them one at a time to see what happens.